# EKS pod to RDS connectivity

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, amazon-eks, connectivity

Trying to check connection to RDS-postgres from EKS pod, unable to connect. Below are the details-
VPC- 10.0.0.0/16
EKS-
in private subnets:- (10.0.1.0/24, 10.0.2.0/24).  AZ-a and AZ-b
security-groups:-  control-plane and worker-node-sec-group.

RDS-postgres
db subnet-group:-  (10.0.3.0/24, 10.0.4.0/24)  AZ-a and AZ-b
DB is deployed in 10.0.3.0/24 (AZ-a)
sec-group:-  db-subnet-group
=> allowing traffic from both EKS cluster security group.
=> also, from whole vpc  10.0.0.0/16.  on port 5432.

NACL, route table entries seems ok. everything is allowed.
Anything missing which needs to be configured ?

Answer (score 0):

Outbound rule was missing in EKS worker node security group. Updated to allow outbound traffic for port 5432 and destination as db security group.
I was under impression that security groups are by default stateful. It means everything is allowed to go out for destination 0.0.0.0/0. **However, you can modify/delete outbound rules.**
In my case, I was deploying EKS using terraform EKS module and this module was allowing only required outbound traffic.

Comment: do one thing try to ssh into EC2 of eks nodegroup and run psql query to connect to RDS.

Comment: may i know why ?